# Use of Technology at the Tabletop

Tags: tools, tool-recommendation

I am relatively new to tabletop rpgs. I am currently involved in a dragon age game with some friends and I am loving it. I've seen a few tools for managing online campaigns like roll20 and rpgtools. The more I play, though, the more I like the idea of the GM and players managing the game state through some sort of application for in person campaigns as well. I envision that an application for this purpose may include things like:

- self updating character sheets
- inventory management for players
- initiative calculator
- roll calculators for various things like combat and skills
- GM scripted encounters, etc...

I am a developer by trade and think this might be an interesting side project to take on. But given that my experience with tabletop rpgs is limited I am curious as how experienced players feel about the use of technology at the table with a live group of people, specifically (not online).

Would the use of an application on a tablet or smartphone get in the way of the experience provided by paper lists and dice rolls?

Are there any specific tools as a player or GM that you'd like to see in an application for in person campaigns?

Do there already exist any tools for managing games like this?

Comment: Sorry, this is off topic here. We're not a discussion site or a place to ask for opinions, thoughts, or market research. See our [tour] for more details on why this question will soon be voted closed.

Comment: You'd probably find people in the [chat] willing to engage you on this.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much higher potential distraction factor from electronic devices (laptops, tablets, etc) than dice & paper.

- Devices have glowing screens and animation that tends to capture and retrain one's attention far more than traditional materials.
- Devices can do many other things, and may pop up distractions like an email notification
- People often huddle behind a laptop screen, effectively blocking out outside stimuli (that is, the other players) while they use the device.

It's very easy for devices to become an unintended social barrier at the table.  I've seen these factors play out repeatedly over years of tabletop gaming and observation of many different people.  It gets disheartening when I've made time to enjoy a face-to-face activity with people, and someone spends it hiding behind a laptop or fiddling with a smartphone game whenever their character isn't directly engaged.

That's not to say devices lack redeeming use, or can't be used responsibly.  As a GM, I'll load my core rulebook onto my phone, because using the electronic index on it faster for quick lookups and it's much easier than lugging a fancy, 450pg book around.  Some people find dice-rolls apps or PDF character sheets to be convenient enough to justify their use.

When using devices at the table, it's important to view them as secondary to the interpersonal interactions and having a role that's limited to their tabletop gaming functions.  When I GM, I do not set a firm policy about device use, but I do discourage too much of it.  I always remind myself when I pick up my own device to only look up the rule, then stop and put my attention back on the players.

If you are considering using a device-based tool for your entire table, it is worth having a short talk with your players about avoiding that distraction trap and treating the device a replacement for paper, rather than just getting sucked into all the cool stuff your tablet does.  This talk isn't about policing players, but acknowledging everyone's human foibles and pledging to work together cooperatively.  I'm just as susceptible to distraction as my players, after all.

Answer (score 4):

In the group I was GMing for a while we only had a relatively small table and six people (including myself) around it. The table was usually cluttered with chips, pizza, drinks, character sheets and dice. Whenever it came to unrolling the battlemap chaos ensued.

So I decided to use my laptop and connect the TV as a second screen. The battlemap I used was on roll20, and on my screen I used Firefox with my own GM account (so I could reveal and hide some areas), and on the TV was a Chrome browser logged in as an ordinary player character. Furthermore I put a wireless mouse on the table and my players were able to move their tokens on screen. It was great: good initiative tracker and very detailed maps on the computer/TV, and I also turned on screen/voice recording for archiving our sessions. And the table could still be used for my players' character sheets and dice.

So this easy setup was a huge help in our gaming sessions.